# Which is better: `iter` or `while` for looping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I know two ways to continuously `input` until certain condition.

One is `while`:

```
a=input()
while a!='a':
    a=input()
```

And another is `iter`:

```
a=input()
for i in iter(lambda: a,'a'):
    a=input()
```

As Nosklo says, better:

```
for i in iter(input,'a'):
    pass
```

I am just wondering which is better (preferred).

Comment: The first would be preferred if you (or others) are expected to later translate to other languages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you're going to use the `for` version, at least don't `lambda` it to ugliness:

```
for a in iter(input, 'a'):
    ....
```

Comment: `for a in ...` even

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which one would be officially "preferred", but I personally much prefer the first one, since I can read it and it's immediately obvious what it does. It strikes me as generally more Pythonic also. ("Explicit is better than implicit.")

The one thing I don't like is the repetition of `input()`. So if it was me I would probably write it like this:

```
while True:
    a = input()
    if a=='a':
        break
```

or this:

```
finished = False
while not finished:
    a = input()
    if a=='a':
        finished = True
```

while these are less concise than the `iter` based versions they are easier to read, especially if you don't regularly use `iter()`. They are also more flexible, since it becomes easy to add other 'special' input commands besides `a`, if you end up needing to do that in the future.